# Dependence; independence; orthogonality counterexample.

Tags: linear-algebra

Adapted from Axler

[image]

I am having trouble understanding the underlined statement.

Let's say $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $(u_1, u_2) = (e_1, e_2)$ be linearly independent in $V$ and $(w_1, w_2, w_3) = (2e_1, 2e_2, e_1)$

Step 1: So after the first $u_1$ has been added we have $(e_1, 2e_1, 2e_2, e_1)$. So applying the lemma, I can remove **some** but not **each** (and every) vector in this new tuple so that the tuple still spans $V$. So let me throw away the $e_1$ in the last entry. This gives me

$$(e_1, 2e_1, 2e_2)$$

Step2: Now I repeat and I add $u_2$ to this list and I get $$(e_2, e_1, 2e_1, 2e_2)$$

Here is what gets confusing. It's telling me that one of the vectors in $(e_2, e_1, 2e_1, 2e_2)$ is in the span of the other and it is saying that it cannot be $(u_1, u_2)$ because it is linearly independent and thus must be a vector in $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$. But this doesn't make sense to me since I can take $e_2$ and write it as

$$e_2 = 2e_2 + 0e_1 + 0(2e_1)$$

So no problem by taking a vector from $(u_1, u_2)$.

I also do not understand what the contradiction at the very end is since I don't even understand the $j$th step.

Comment: It's not really well written; the fact is that surely one of the remaining $w$ vectors can be removed and this is what allows the induction to go on. It *can* happen that one of the $u$ vectors is a linear combination of the others, but not in all cases (for instance when also the $w$ list is linearly independent).

Comment: He says "one of the vectors is in the span *of the previous ones*".

Comment: What is the contradiction? Is it what egeg said?

Comment: Do you mind answering that question using the example I gave? This is too abstract for me.

Comment: At the end of each step, the list spans $V$. So if no $w$'s were left in the list, there could be no $u$ left outside the list either.

Comment: In your step 2, you can't remove $e_2$. You are looking for a vector that is in the span of the preceding vectors on the list. The first two won't work.  The removed vector would have to be one of the $w_i$.  It's the underlined bit in the image that makes this work, you always add the $u$'s to the "left side" of the list".

Comment: @DavidMitra, okay I got you now. But I need you to spell out one obvious thing to me. Yes if no $w$ to throw out, it means no $u$ can be added either. Yes I realize there is something wrong if we add $u$ to the list and not have any $w$s thrown out, but what is *it* (the contradiction)

Comment: Well. The list spans. If you  add a $u_i$, it would be a dependent set. But if the list has only $u_i$'s...

Comment: If the list only has $u_i$, then it may not span $V$. We never assumed it can span $V$.